# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './scroll-view'

Tags: ionic4, production

im having a problem at run time only when build with --prod flag

im using vscode with

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.5 
      (C:\Users\elile\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.3.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.8
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```

Cordova:

```
   Cordova CLI       : not installed
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 9 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.8
```

System:

```
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (D:\android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './scroll-view'
    at n (main.c989e908effa4371039e.js:1)
    at main.c989e908effa4371039e.js:1
    at main.c989e908effa4371039e.js:1
    at Object.gyxb (main.c989e908effa4371039e.js:1)
    at r (runtime.d5af43206892a58fb713.js:1)
    at Module.zUnb (main.c989e908effa4371039e.js:1)
    at r (runtime.d5af43206892a58fb713.js:1)
    at Object.0 (main.c989e908effa4371039e.js:1)
    at r (runtime.d5af43206892a58fb713.js:1)
    at f (runtime.d5af43206892a58fb713.js:1)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have used Scroll View module but not put it into the parent modules declarations.

Check every place that you have used Scroll View and see if the module is defined in that parent module.

## update

if its an issue with the packages then I would generate a new app and then either copy the package versions back to your current broken app, or just migrate the app into the new app.

Comment: im not using scroll-view

in node_modules\ionic-angular\umd\util\events.js  

var scroll_view_1 = require("./scroll-view");  this line require the model

Comment: i have tried that with no luck . if i comment out the require from the model then im getting cannot find model (different model name ) 
something with the references goes wrong i guess on production

Comment: I dont have anything more to suggest from the information you have given. It's likely something to do with one of the packages needing an update but you haven't given many details about the code so I can't look anything up for compatibility. You need to find out what you can disable to stop the error and then research that package and see if it has some kind of info about solving it. You are using something that's not compatible obviously.

Answer (score 0):

> The plugin breaks with ionic 4, ionic-angular became @ionic/angular.
>
> If you have used "ionic-angular" library for import  then changed for ionic 4
>
> Change "ionic-angular" to "@ionic/angular"
>
> > Like that : import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';